# Save specific line from text via batch

Tags: batch-file, text

So I'm trying to save the contents from the second line of a text file as a variable using Batch. I know there are way better scripting languages to do this with, but batch has command line simplicity that I need. I found this webpage: http://www.netikka.net/tsneti/info/tscmd023.htm But it seems that this method requires an auxiliary program called SED be installed. Are there any methods that do not require SED?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A for loop could work ..

```
     @echo off

     Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

     For /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%a in (myfile.txt) do (

     Set secondline=%%a 

     goto finish

     )

    : finish

    Echo this is my variable !secondline!

    Pause
```

Comment: Place the batch file in the directory that contains the text file